# Using bash script to automate executable runs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am relatively new to bash scripting. I have a linux executable that takes one user input from the command line. That is, I can run the executable like this: **./executable [input]**. I want to run the executable multiple times with different inputs, that is, something like this:

```
$ ./executable 16
$ ./executable 32
....
```

I want to use a bash script for my purpose. This is my attempt (which is simply incorrect):

```
for i in 1 2 3 ... 10
do
  temp = 16 * $i
  ./executable temp
done
```

How would I get this done?

Comment: Suraaj. Try to edit the description and make more clear what exactly you want. It is not clear yet.

Comment: @ruud, is it better now?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you are new to shell scripting, may I recommend [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for reference, and [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) - also available as standalone tool - for debugging scripts?

Comment: equal sign with spaces does compare (not assign), your calculation can be done with arithmetic expansion or with external tool like expr, glob should be escaped \\* and to call a value of variable you need $ sign

Comment: @pLumo this question isn't about integer mathematics, it's about iterating over a range.  That answer is not a good fit, because it doesn't include the basic syntax for iterating over a range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for((i=16;i<=160;i=i+16)); do
  ./executable "$i"
done
```

Comment: @pLumo Just habit, I guess. Plus the given structure. Who expects potential for extended thinking in a task like this...

Comment: Seems that `for i in {1..10}; do ./executable $((i*16)); done` is easier to read? Perhaps it's just me

Comment: @roaima Yeah, I should have put more thinking into this. I thought I just fix the OP's code rather than thinking about a better approach. But the `temp` was completely useless. One could argue that mine saves one computation over yours. 8-)  I guess I would even prefer a pure counting loop head and do the "real math" elsewhere for better understanding. That's probably why I did not come to this on my own. But: I really don't like brace expansion with numbers.